# Regex match newline in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have to get the value from a textarea using jQuery and count the number of newlines there. I'd like to do this using a regex-expression. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Why do you "like to do this using a regex-expression"?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

regex does not have count. better use array like this

```
var val = textarea.value;
var arr = val.split(/[\n\r]/g);
var count = arr.length;
```

you could condense this in less rows and vars...

```
var count = $('textarea').val().split(/[\n\r]/g).length;
```

Comment: What splits a string is usually less in quantity than the split parts. By 1.

Comment: a slightly better solution would be `$('textarea').val().match(/[\n\r]/g).length`

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/qxKmW/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = $("#txtField").val();
    parts = str.split(/[\n\r]/g);
    var newline_count = parts.length;
    alert("Count: " + newline_count);
});
```